# QHBoxLayout has incorrect width

Tags: qt

Hello :) This is my code (with what I tried in comment). "this" is a class derived from QWidget, and "this" has no size because I want to fit it depending on the size of childs (so in the "paintEvent", I call "adjustSize()") :

```
QPushButton *button1 = new QPushButton("Hello and good morning");
QPushButton *button2 = new QPushButton("World");

QHBoxLayout *h1 = new QHBoxLayout(this);
QHBoxLayout *h2 = new QHBoxLayout(this);
QVBoxLayout *v = new QVBoxLayout(this);

h1->addWidget(button1);
h2->addWidget(button2);
//h2->setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetMaximumSize);
//h2->setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetDefaultConstraint);
//h2->setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetFixedSize);
//h2->setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetMinAndMaxSize);

v->addLayout(h1);
v->addLayout(h2);
//v->setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetDefaultConstraint);
//v->setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetFixedSize);
//v->setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetMaximumSize);
//v->setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetMinAndMaxSize);
//v->setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetMinimumSize);
//v->setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetNoConstraint);

QSize s1 = h1->sizeHint();
QSize s2 = h2->sizeHint();

QSize s3 = h1->totalSizeHint();
QSize s4 = h2->totalSizeHint();

QSize s5 = h1->totalMaximumSize();
QSize s6 = h2->totalMaximumSize();

QSize s7 = h1->totalMinimumSize();
QSize s8 = h2->totalMinimumSize();
setLayout(v);
show();
```

I get this result : Only the button1 is visible. When I put a breakpoint at "setLayout(v)" I see that each QSize of h2 has a size of (0, 0).

My question is : How can I see the button2 (and the button1 of course :) ) ? I don't want to set a min/max size because the button has to fit with its text.

Have a good day !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The layout is set directly to the widget passed as parameter in the constructor of your layout. But, a widget can have only one layout at the same time.

Remove the `this` parameter and it should work.

```
QHBoxLayout *h1 = new QHBoxLayout();
QHBoxLayout *h2 = new QHBoxLayout();
QVBoxLayout *v = new QVBoxLayout();
```